# Clipping raster and shapefile and generate attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, clip

I have a shapefile folder of property map  and raster file of elevation. I want to clip those and generate attribute table.

I import both shapefile and raster file, then I click 'Full extent' and remove color to Hollow.

[image]

After clipping I can get a new clipped raster layer. But, I cannot generate the attribute table for the clipping.  My key purpose is to get the elevation data from raster for each ID available in shapefile.

Comment: Only Integer rasters have attribute tables. So if the resulting clipped raster is of type float then there will be no raster attribute table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Zonal Statistics as Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm). Use your property shapefile as the input zone field, and your elevation layer as the input raster. The output will be a table with raster statistics (mean, min, max, etc.) for each input zone (i.e. ID in your shapefile). This table can then be joined back to your shapefile as additional attributes if that's useful.

Comment: Thank you very much!